# How many evolutions can be done in 30 minutes

Tags: pokemon-go

Basically the title says it all. If your trying to save up evolutions to do them during a single lucky egg, how many evolutions can one do in a 30 min period to maximize the time of the egg?

Comment: Depends on how many times the server crashes?

Comment: This question goes to prove how much a speed-based mechanic like this is flawed. The mechanic should be for a fixed number of evolutions so no amount of server failure or app-switching will penalise players. ([Excuse me while I cringe at having to use the word 'app'](http://starecat.com/content/wp-content/uploads/software-terminology-back-then-many-words-now-all-called-app.jpg))

Comment: Also, even before using the lucky egg to do the evolutions, try to be very near to hatch 9 10km eggs, they can give you a very high amount of exp, Scythe gave me 3k yesterday without lucky egg.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Depends on how fast the game runs on your phone, but following this **[video](https://youtu.be/LZnHmS4xOTI?t=5m40s)**

20 seconds for the evolution animation

6 seconds if it's new and being registered to pokedex

And some time inbetween. If we say you're fast and can get to the next one in on average 6 seconds (I assume many of them would be the same, ie. pidgeys)

If we then assume the pokedex wont be a problem;
26 seconds each
30 minutes

That gives ~69 evolutions, provided it's the same for all pokemon.

Less if you gotta deal with the pokedex

Comment: Since the new pokedex entry give as much point as evolutions, even if you do less evolutions, you will have a much better ratio time/points.

Comment: Is this still true? I've heard that they've shortened the animation length.

Answer (score 7):

## Upward of 70, conventionally. More, with luck. With additional hardware, beyond 200.

As calculated in the other answers, yes, you can easily induce more than 60 evolutions in half an hour by simply focusing. I think I've gotten up to 71, this way. But that's not the maximum.

**Restarting the app can be faster than the evolution animation.** On a current-gen phone, on good internet, when the servers have a light load, you can exit the game and then get back through the log-in process in as little as half the time it takes to wait out an evolution. In this fashion, evolution sprees of more than 100 Pokémon are attested.

**You can log in to the same account on more than one device to multithread your evolution sprees.** In this way, the only cap on your evolutions-per-minute is how fast you can operate the game interfaces. I have personally operated three phones at once, moving through them in a repeating wave, and evolved more than 200 Pokemon in one half-hour.

You can, given the opportunity, also combine these two techniques. Sounds like a real chore to me, though.

Please note that undertaking these tactics is not *strictly* against the game's terms of service, but account sharing *is*, so it is naturally against the rules to enlist a friend to help you manage multiple devices (they could still loan you a device, though.) Whether or not these tactics qualify as *cheats*, however, is left to your sense of conscience. Most games with a multiplayer element will absolutely not permit multiple game sessions on one account, so it's not like it would be wierd to see an exploitative element in these methods.

Theoretically, a third-party program abusing the deobfuscated game API could evolve your entire inventory near-instantaneously, but doing so would **absolutely** not be permissable under the TOS. Regardless, a cheater can do up to 1000 (the maximum number of Pokémon you can hold, after bag upgrades) during the activation period of just one lucky egg, plus however many more his teleporting bot can catch before the half-hour is over.

Comment: There has been a report in December from a Reddit user who was banned for using two devices at once.  https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/5juys8/discussion_psa_lucky_egg_evolving_on_two_devices/

Answer (score 6):

One single evolution takes exactly(ish) 25 seconds for the animation to fully play out, meaning that you can't do anything during that time. So if we account for user speed we can estimate that you can do 2 a minute, meaning you would be able to do 60 evolution's in a 30 minute period.

Comment: cant u close and reopen the app to skip the evolution animation?

Comment: I'm almost positive opening the app takes a lot longer than 25 seconds.

Comment: You can but the time it will take to close and reopen it could last longer than 25 seconds that the animation will take-depending on the servers- and it might not even register as you triggering the evolution, so you'd have to do the evolution sequence again.

Answer (score -1):

i suppose it would be helpful to write down your plan of attack so you are not spending time selecting pokemon that cant evolve as you select them.
make a list.. also.. if you plan on making a volteon then rename your eevee before you initiate the lucky egg .. stuff like that.. also.. one more thing...

dont try to do it during peek hours.. when you notice that the servers go down.  i once started a lucky egg and then i got that spinning ball that makes you restart.. and then i couldnt log back in because google pokemon was down for more than 30 minutes and i lost the egg.. i got a few in but from now on im gonna do it from my home wifi not out and about where 4g might be spotty.. even if it means im sitting near a lure.. because my goal is to evolve like above, 68 or more if possible. thats much more than any pokemons that a lure attracts ..

so to do the math..
30 minutes
2 per minute = 60 average
each evolution so 1000 xp each would mean 60,000 xp.. is that right?  so currently im at level 21.. and i have 4200/75000 still to go.  doing this would bring me very close to level 22. and i would skip that leveling up animation if i were to do it now.  because i wouldnt reach 75000

now i need to see how many evolutions i actually have in my deck.. i dont think i have 60...

fun game