# What changed in the evolution animation?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was doing a lucky egg evolution marathon last night and noticed that the animation for evolutions changed. This is with the latest patch v0.33.0.

I can tell it was different but couldn't quite pinpoint exactly what. More research today confirms that it did change, and some new things like how you [no longer get to see Rattata's butt.](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4wzeks/fyi_the_evolution_animation_did_change/)

I also noticed that after evolving a pokemon you already have in your dex, there is a 5 second long staring contest with your new pokemon as if your pokemon got amnesia and is getting to know your name again.

So what change... the butt shots? More importantly, is the new animation longer or shorter, or the same?

Comment: I'm taking timings right now and will post the results soon. I'll have 2 sets of GIFs as proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some timings. I started the time at the white flash and ended it when the actions screen is able to be pressed.

These results aren't comphrehensive but it gives you a good idea. About **~21-22 seconds** for a normal evolution and about **~24-26 seconds** for a 'new to Pokedex' evolution.

This doesn't seem to be too different from **[what it was before](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/276386/125786)**, but then again I don't know how the person in that answer came up with his numbers.

### New to Pokedex Evolution:

Time: 24.05

Pokemon: Staryu to Starmie

> [Click for GIF](https://i.imgur.com/OkX229e.gifv)

Time: 25.25

Pokemon: Eevee to Flareon

> [Click for GIF](https://i.imgur.com/pf6zCZX.gifv)

### Normal Evolution:

Time: 21.05 sec

Pokemon: Pidgey to Pidgeotto

> [Click for GIF](https://i.imgur.com/5PN0Xib.gifv)

Time: 21.24 sec

Pokemon: Rattata to Raticate

> [Click for GIF](https://i.imgur.com/boPtDzn.gifv)

Comment: Great, thanks for the GIFs. Would love to compare your normal evolutions to an old one, but all the ones I found on youtube were new pokedex entries. Looks like it is still roughly the same if not less.

Comment: @gitsitgo Oh yeah I didn't even think to do that. Glad it helped though

Comment: Please note that on May 15, 2023, [Imgur will remove content that is not tied to a user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/162827). This may affect the media you included in your post since they were not uploaded through SE Imgur. I recommend that you reupload the media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You may need to edit the media to make it smaller than 2 MiB, which is the maximum size allowed by SE Imgur.